# asp menu not working after partial postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a asp:menu that stops functioning after I perform a search on my page. The search uses a update panel and is triggered by a submit button. Once the results are displayed on the page the menu hover effects stop working. It will no longer expand down on mouseover. The clickable links still work.

The menu is in the site's master page and is outside the update panel of the search control.

Thank you for any help!

This is the menu

```
  <asp:Menu ID="Menu5" runat="server" 
                                        DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
                                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                                         RenderingMode="List"
                                         StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
                                         StaticPopOutImageUrl="~/Images/DownArrow.png"
                                         Visible="False" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black">

                                        <Items>
                                            <asp:MenuItem PopOutImageUrl="~/Images/bullet.png" Selectable="False" Text="Add" >
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Item" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/CreateItem.aspx" ></asp:MenuItem>
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/CreateContact.aspx" ></asp:MenuItem>
                                            </asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Update" Selectable="False" Value="Update">
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Item" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/UpdateItem.aspx" Value="Item"></asp:MenuItem>
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/UpdateContact.aspx" Value="Contact"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            </asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Approve" Selectable="False"  Value="Approve" >
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Item" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ApproveItem.aspx" Value="Item"></asp:MenuItem>
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ApproveContact.aspx" Value="Contact"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            </asp:MenuItem>
                                        </Items>
                                         <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="10px" />
                                    </asp:Menu>
```

This is the Button Click event

```
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {


            string keyword = txtSearch.Text.Trim();
             List<dynamic> results = SearchItems(keyword);
             List<dynamic> Cresults = SearchContacts(keyword);




            //bind and return
            lv.DataSource = results;
            lv.DataBind();


            //Contact Bind return
            LVC.DataSource = Cresults;
            LVC.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the asp:menu inside the UpdatePanel? If it is, it's probably reloading the menu again, including any javascript/jQuery that comes with it, which would cause script duplicates that may confuse the browser.

Comment: @MickaelCaruso  No its on the masterpage. I just added that to the question. Not apart of the update panel.

Comment: Post some code, both the code-behind and front side.

Comment: @Mark Posted everything i think would help.

Comment: @jackncoke Where is the mouseover code that causes it to expand down?  Is it jquery?

Comment: that is the trick. It is a draggable menu from the toolbox in vs 2012. i just replaced it with a jquery menu that i made with html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is not to use the drag and drop menus from VS 2012. I replaced this with a Jquery Menu that wrote and have had no issues since.